# What are the name and inverse of an interesting integer matrix?

Tags: matrices, random-matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory, matrix-inverse

It is practicable to compute the matrix inverses
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 2^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
&=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{3}{2} & 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{pmatrix},\\
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 2^2 & 2^3 \\
 1 & 3 & 3^2 & 3^3 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{11}{6} & 3 & -\frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 1 & -\frac{5}{2} & 2 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} \\
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 2^2 & 2^3 & 2^4 \\
 1 & 3 & 3^2 & 3^3 & 3^4 \\
 1 & 4 & 4^2 & 4^3 & 4^4 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{25}{12} & 4 & -3 & \frac{4}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{35}{24} & -\frac{13}{3} & \frac{19}{4} & -\frac{7}{3} & \frac{11}{24} \\
 -\frac{5}{12} & \frac{3}{2} & -2 & \frac{7}{6} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{24} & -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{24} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Generally, what is the inverse $M_{n+1}^{-1}$ of the interesting integer matrix
\begin{equation*}
M_{n+1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & \dotsm & 0 & 0\\
 1 & 1 & 1 & \dotsm & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 2 & 2^{2} & \dotsm & 2^{n-1} & 2^{n}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
 1 & n-1 & (n-1)^{2} & \dotsm & (n-1)^{n-1} & (n-1)^{n}\\
 1 & n & n^{2} & \dotsm & n^{n-1} & n^{n}
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$? What is the name of the matrix $M_{n+1}$?

Comment: Interestingly, the sum in each row of is zero:
\begin{align*}
 -\frac{3}{2} + 2-\frac{1}{2}&=0, &
 \frac{1}{2} -1 + \frac{1}{2} &=0, \\
 -\frac{11}{6} + 3 -\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{3} &=0, &
 1 -\frac{5}{2} + 2 -\frac{1}{2} &=0, \\
 -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} &=0, &
 -\frac{25}{12} + 4 -3 + \frac{4}{3} -\frac{1}{4} &=0, \\
 \frac{35}{24} -\frac{13}{3} + \frac{19}{4} -\frac{7}{3} + \frac{11}{24} &=0, &
 -\frac{5}{12} + \frac{3}{2} -2 + \frac{7}{6} -\frac{1}{4} &=0, \\
 \frac{1}{24} -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{24} &=0. &
\end{align*}

Comment: related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Interestingly, the sum of all elements in every second column is $1$, otherwise, each sum of each column is $0$:
\begin{align*}
1-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}&=0, & 0+2-1&=1, & 0-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}&=0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
1-\frac{11}{6}+1-\frac{1}{6}&=0, & 0+3-\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{2}&=1, \\
0-\frac{3}{2}+2-\frac{1}{2}&=0, & 0+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}&=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: For the third $5\times5$ inverse matrix, the sum of all elements in the second column is $1$, each sum in other column (except the second column) is $0$:
\begin{align*}
1-\frac{25}{12}+\frac{35}{24}-\frac{5}{12}+\frac{1}{24}&=0, & 0+4-\frac{13}{3}+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{6}&=1, \\
0-3+\frac{19}{4}-2+\frac{1}{4}&=0, & 0+\frac{4}{3}-\frac{7}{3}+\frac{7}{6}-\frac{1}{6}&=0, \\
0-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{11}{24}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{24}&=0. &
\end{align*}

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, it's a special case of the Vandermonde matrix. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried computing the inverse, as outlined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix#Inverse_Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: The polynomial $f(x) = (x-0)(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$ is computed with the Stirling numbers of the first kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser I wish to derive a simpler form of the inverse of my specific matrix $M_{n+1}$, because the expression for the inverse of the general Vandermonde matrix is too complicated for me.

Comment: It seems that I found out a better solution to the inverse of my specific Vandermonde matrix $M_{n+1}$ at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240061354. Where was this paper formally published?

Comment: A perfect solution is included in "N. Macon and A. Spitzbart, *Inverses of Vandermonde matrices*, Amer. Math. Monthly **65** (1958), no. 2, 95--100; available online at https://doi.org/10.2307/2308881"

Comment: I am very pleased to announce that I have derived a very beautiful solution to the inverse of the specific Vandermonde matrix $M_{n+1}$. Thank you all for your attentions and supports.